# How to update database to match another database from WebApi?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, sqlite, asp.net-web-api

Ive got a simple `WebApi` with a database and a `Universal Windows App` with `SQLite` database in it. I want to download data from `WebApi` and save that data locally on my device. What is the best way to download only `Changes` in the database, but not all the data?

Comment: Do you mean schema changes? Is this database first (edmx) or code first? If code first, that is what migrations are for.

Comment: Yes, code first. migrations used for `table` changes, but i need to sync `data` from that table. For example, after app start, it download all the data from `WebApi`, purge old local data and then insert new one. But that concept is too stupid

Comment: Take a look at this: http://litereplica.io/